# Updating job status in KUE node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, queue, jobs, kue

I create a job:

```
var kue = require('kue');
var queue = kue.createQueue();

//name of the queue is myQueue
var job = queue.create('myQueue', {
    from: 'process1',
    type: 'testMessage',
    data: {
        msg: 'Hello world!'
    }
}).save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to save ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('Job ' + job.id + ' saved to the queue.');
    }
});
```

Is there a way I can update the job status (i.e. active, failed, in progress) myself? So for example:

The consumer picks up the job:

```
queue.process('myQueue', function(job, done){
  console.log('IN HERE', job.state) // returns function
});
```

This is the function that is returned from the above:

```
function ( state, fn ) {
  if( 0 == arguments.length ) return this._state;
  var client   = this.client
    , fn       = fn || noop;
  var oldState = this._state;
  var multi    = client.multi();
```

And I want to hardcode a job state e.g. `job.state = 'failed'` and allow myself to update the job status when I want to?

Is this possible in Kue?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer, yes, you can use job.failed() or send an error back to done.

```
queue.process('myQueue', function(job, done){
  console.log('IN HERE', job.state) // returns function

  job.failed();
  done(new Error('bad'));
});
```

However, it sounds like you want to handle the processing yourself. You can setup your own function like this.

```
queue.on('job enqueue', function(id, type){
   console.log( 'Job %s got queued of type %s', id, type );
   kue.Job.get(id, function(err, job){
      if (err) return;
      // do your custom processing here
      if( something was processed ){
         job.complete();
      }else{
         job.failed();
      }
   });
});
```

Here's a few more options you can also use.

```
job.inactive(); 
job.active();
job.complete();
job.delayed();
```

There's some examples on this page.
https://github.com/Automattic/kue

Comment: However I do not want to put the job in failed state. The other functions do not allow me to achieve what I want